# laravel crear formularios en pdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

Estoy usando Laravel 5.8 y la librería barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. Ya he notado que tiene algunas dificultades con ciertas clases de bootstrap, en concreto, con algunas que expresan medidas en unidades relativas. Sin embargo, mi problema es el siguiente. Tengo que crear en pdf un formulario editable. Lo que hago (por empezar a probar) es lo siguiente. En priemr lugar, creo una vista para el formulario en `resources/views/pages/form.blade.php`, así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {{-- CSRF Token --}}
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    {{-- Styles for the site --}}
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Esto es un formulario en PDF</h1>
        </div>
        <form action="{{ route('grabar_form') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4 text-right">
                    <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Es muy simplona, pero de momento, solo es una prueba.

En el controlador tengo un método para sacar este formulario, así:

```
public function form_pdf()
{
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadView('pages.form');
    return $pdf->stream();
}
```

El pdf lo saca por pantalla, pero totalmente descolocado, y el campo no es editable, cuando necesito generar el formulario, de modo que el usuario pueda escribir en el campo. En pantalla me queda algo así:

[image: formulario mal obtenido]

Si lo descargo, cambiando la línea `return $pdf->stream();` por `return $pdf->download();` el resultado es el mismo. Un formulario descolocado e inutilizable.

¿Cómo puedo lograr estos formularios en PDF usando Laravel?

Para los que dicen que "a qué me refiero con un formulario editable en PDF", me refiero a [esto](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y-qR-karWBQDWE1HVbgG8Is7zJmFgFFS) Hay que abrirlo con acrobat o con el navegador, no con el visor de documentos de google.

Comment: "Tengo que crear en pdf un formulario editable" podrias explicar eso, a que te refieres con eso de: "crear en pdf un formulario editable"??? ahora bien si el error es solo las posiciones de tu input respecto a los label, te recomiendo que no utilices `div`, ni tampoco bootstrap y en lo personal deja de utilizar `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` es una de las peores librerias para pdf, pero si decides no cambiarlo trabaja con `table`s, `tr`s y `td`s, para matequetar tu pdf.

Comment: No sabía que esa librería fuera tan conflictiva, cual me sugieres? Por "formulario editable" me refiero a esos formularios que están en pdf y el usuario puede rellenar los campos y guardarlos, como esos que se ven a veces en las páginas de las Administraciones Públicas, o de grandes corporaciones.

Comment: Bueno, con las tablas se mejora un poco la colocación, aunque hay estilos, como las alineaciones de textos, que no funcionan. Y aun así, en los campos no se puede escribir, el pdf sigue sin funcionar como formulario. Que librería sería adecuada para hacer esto en laravel?